# CORB - Facing a CORB error preveneting loading of an external JS file

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking, incognito-mode

I am getting a CORB error in **Chrome Incognito mode** while trying to load an external Javascript file to the DOM. Onething to note is CORS was enabled for this external JSfile and it's working in the normal mode.

**Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html.**

On Page load I am trying to add an external JS file to Dom using

```
script = docuemnt.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'js-file.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Response from js-file.js was blocked in chrome incognito mode. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading `js-file.js` from the same origin/domain as your website? Can you provide response headers for `js-file.js` load request?

Comment: @farhodius: js-file.js is not from the same domain.  For that purpose  CORS was enabled.

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 15:05:12 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-store
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Do you have control over the server hosting your `js-file.js`? Some websites can detect if you are browsing in incognito mode and prevent you from reading their content. Does issue persist in Firefox incognito mode as well?

Comment: @farhodius I dont have access to server. I didn't check firefox incognito. It's working fine in Edge private mode.